# Differentiable maps between topological spaces

Tags: differential-topology

Is it possible to define differentiable maps between topological spaces without using the idea of manifolds? I mean with using just the topological structure (open sets or neighborhoods).

Comment: You must be more precise in what you are willing to do. The answer to your question is depending on.

Comment: You can define anything you like, I suppose.  It's especially easy if the object you want to define has no role to play.

Comment: I just mean the definition. Is there any definition of differentiability of maps between topological space.

Comment: What properties would you like the definition to satisfy ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative

Comment: you can say that differential topology is dealing with differentiable functions on differentiable manifolds. My question is dealing with differentiable functions on topological space in general. Is there an analogy in general topological space without any added structure or restrictions?

Comment: The very notion of differentiability involves measuring distances at least to some order (think Taylor formula), so I do not see that one could expect anything interesting with only a topological structure. But unless you precisely state what is goal, this is not a question that can be answered.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "goal"? Please give examples.

Comment: After reading the answer by Todd Trimble, I voted for reopening. But the question should be improved. @Almariah: could you provide some context? From where did you get the idea that a surrogate of the notion of differentiable maps could be available for (some classes of?) topological spaces? ....

Comment: If you have any suggestion for improving the question, please post it!

Comment: Here is a completely random idea. Suppose that $X$ is a topological space without isolated points and $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $K=\mathbb{C}$, and $f,g:X\rightarrow K$. Then we say that $\frac{dg}{df}(x_{0})$ exists if there is a dense open set $U\subseteq X$ where $\frac{dg}{df}(x_{0})=^{\lim}_{x\in U,x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{g(x)-g(x_{0})}{f(x)-f(x_{0})}$ exists.

Comment: Joseph Van Name: you should define a metric on $X$ at first for you idea to be right or have a meaning. I am not sure. This like the answer of Todd Trimble, on metric space.

Comment: Abdullah Almariah. The notion of a limit makes sense  general topological spaces. To make my definition more precise, $^{\lim}_{x\in U,x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{g(x)-g(x_{0})}{f(x)-f(x_{0})}=L$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an open neighborhood $O$ of $x_{0}$ where if $x\in O\cap U$, then $|\frac{g(x)-g(x_{0})}{f(x)-f(x_{0})}-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Joseph Van Name: You are right. I got confused because you have defined a function between a topological space and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Joseph Van Name: Do you have any analogous random idea for $f,g : X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces?

Comment: I currently have no analogous idea for maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces, and I doubt that it is even possible without adding extra structure to the topological spaces.

Comment: Perhaps  the  following  algebraic  formulation could work::Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact topological space and $A=C(X)$ and $B=C(Y)$ be the $C^{*}$ algebra of complex valued continuoes functions on $X$ and $Y$ resp.Choose (and fix) two dense subalgebra $A'$ of $A$ and $B'$ of $B$. every continuous function on $f:X \rightarrow Y$ define a natural morphism $f^{*}$from $B$ to $A$ we can say that $f$ is $A'-B'$ differentiable if $f^{*}(B) \subset A$. This could be considered as a natural generalization of standard differentability for maps between manifold.

Comment: Ali Taghavi: What do you mean with complex valued continuous functions on $X$ and $Y$, whereas you have defined $X$ and $Y$ as topological spaces?

Comment: $C(X)$ is the space of all continuous function from X to $\mathbb{C}$. This is a $C^{*}$ algebra.

Comment: Why is the question closed, although no one can answer it? Using topological structure we can define continuous functions and convergent sequences. Why differentiable functions could not be defined in terms of the topology?

Comment: I think it is impossible, but why?

Answer (score 2):

While this is not for general topological spaces, you might be interested in a kind of generalization of differential calculus for *metric spaces*, developed by Burroni and Penon [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/23/10/23-10abs.html).

A key notion is that of two functions $f, g: M \to N$ between metric spaces to be *tangent* to each other at a point $a \in M$: this means $f(a) = g(a)$ and the function $C: M \to \mathbb{R}_+$ defined by

$$C(x) = \frac{d(f(x), g(x))}{d(x, a)} \;\; (x \neq a), \qquad C(a) = 0$$

is continuous at $a$. This is an equivalence relation. Then, given pointed metric spaces $(M, a)$ and $(N, b)$, one defines a *jet* $(M, a) \to (N, b)$ to be a tangency equivalence class of locally Lipschitz maps $f: M \to N$ such that $f(a) = b$ ("locally Lipschitz" means there is some $k > 0$ such that $f$ is $k$-Lipschitz when restricted to some neighborhood of $a$). If $f: (M, a) \to (N, b)$ is a based function that is tangent to some locally Lipschitz $g: (M, a) \to (N, b)$ at $a$, then they define the *tangential* (roughly akin to a differential) $T f_a$ to be the corresponding jet, and in that case they say $f$ is "tangentiable" at $a$.

Ultimately Burroni and Penon want to define, given a map $f: M \to N$ between suitable metric spaces, a notion of tangential $tf: M \to {"Jet(M, N)"}$ that plays a role analogous to the differential $df: U \to L(E, E')$ of a differentiable map $f: U \to E'$, where $E, E'$ are normed vector spaces and $U$ is an open set of $E$. They achieve this by considering certain metric spaces equipped with some extra structure, called *transmetric spaces*. But for this I'll have to refer you to the article.